# How to add toggle effect using plain html code?

Tags: html, css

I want that the above code should have drop down toggle effect in my website.

By default the first box must show the drop down box when the audience refresh the page and when the next box is clicked the drop down box of the earlier should hide itself.

How to do that?

```css
.maindrop {
    width: 49%;
}
.bar {
    padding: 20px;
    color: white;
    background: #1FB5AC;
    display: block;
    font-family: Times;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    transition: .2s ease-out;
    margin-bottom: .1cm;
}
.bar:hover {
    background: gray;
}
.dropbox {
    max-height: 0;
    transition: .5s ease-out;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
.dropbox:target {
    max-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="maindrop"  style="float: right">
        <div class="fold default">
            <a class="bar" href="#tab5">Speaker 5</a>
            <div class="dropbox" id='tab5'>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam diam enim, interdum eget iaculis in, pretium non libero. Pellentesque id interdum risus, vitae iaculis ipsum. Duis mi tortor, sodales nec nisl nec, venenatis sollicitudin turpis. Pellentesque hendrerit nec massa sit amet scelerisque. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque a mi sit amet metus hendrerit placerat. Duis ullamcorper lectus vel erat luctus egestas. Maecenas pharetra justo sed nulla blandit, ut viverra diam posuere.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fold">
            <a class="bar" href="#tab6"> Speaker 6</a>
            <div class="dropbox" id='tab6'>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam diam enim, interdum eget iaculis in, pretium non libero. Pellentesque id interdum risus, vitae iaculis ipsum. Duis mi tortor, sodales nec nisl nec, venenatis sollicitudin turpis. Pellentesque hendrerit nec massa sit amet scelerisque. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque a mi sit amet metus hendrerit placerat. Duis ullamcorper lectus vel erat luctus egestas. Maecenas pharetra justo sed nulla blandit, ut viverra diam posuere.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fold">
            <a class="bar" href="#tab7"> Speaker 7</a>
            <div class="dropbox" id='tab7'>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam diam enim, interdum eget iaculis in, pretium non libero. Pellentesque id interdum risus, vitae iaculis ipsum. Duis mi tortor, sodales nec nisl nec, venenatis sollicitudin turpis. Pellentesque hendrerit nec massa sit amet scelerisque. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque a mi sit amet metus hendrerit placerat. Duis ullamcorper lectus vel erat luctus egestas. Maecenas pharetra justo sed nulla blandit, ut viverra diam posuere.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fold">
            <a class="bar" href="#tab8"> Speaker 8</a>
            <div class="dropbox" id='tab8'>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam diam enim, interdum eget iaculis in, pretium non libero. Pellentesque id interdum risus, vitae iaculis ipsum. Duis mi tortor, sodales nec nisl nec, venenatis sollicitudin turpis. Pellentesque hendrerit nec massa sit amet scelerisque. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque a mi sit amet metus hendrerit placerat. Duis ullamcorper lectus vel erat luctus egestas. Maecenas pharetra justo sed nulla blandit, ut viverra diam posuere.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: you wanna toggle this without js right ?

Comment: @ManishPatel sorry.. i have updated... the code

Comment: If they were siblings you could do it (i.e. `a.bar:active + a.bar { display:none; }`), but you can't reach parents or grandparents via `CSS`.

Comment: Do you mean bootstrap - accordian ? http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_collapsible_accordion&stacked=h

Comment: I have added what i have tried for toggle effect using page jump.. But the problem is the speaker5 box is going up..however I want that speaker name also has to be visible with the drop down box...

Comment: feel free to edit my snippet...please..it will help me to get in to it without any problem... Thank you

Comment: Thanks for your code @Meonly. It was very enlightening. Unfortunately, unless you can select the child of parent sibling with `CSS`, I'm not seeing anyway of achieving this.

Comment: @Daerik I dont mind if there is CSS codes if other options are not possible... Please edit my code to achieve this using css

Comment: Refer this page...it will help to identify what difficulty i am facing under the heading "invited speakers" http://iclaa2017.com/slide-show-test/

Comment: @Daerik I am expecting an intuitive answer from you...

Comment: @Meonly You can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector, but there is no way to target `.default`. Even putting the target on `.fold` to select siblings, you are only able to go down, but not up (where `.default` is).

Comment: Going to https://www.domain.tld/your-page.html#tab5 will give you the desired effect, but without targeting the first child initially, there is no way to do this with pure CSS.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try bootstrap -accordian..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Accordion Example</h2>
  <p><strong>Note:</strong> The <strong>data-parent</strong> attribute makes sure that all collapsible elements under the specified parent will be closed when one of the collapsible item is shown.</p>
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Collapsible Group 1</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Collapsible Group 2</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Collapsible Group 3</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Shivkumar  Exactly what I want....How to get the style codes... so that I can edit the color and other things.. like in my code.. I like that color which i have used and want hover effect also in the box.

Comment: I wanted to style the boxed titles like in my code...How to do that here...I think if I get the explicit code for the styling options..it would be good...

Comment: @Meonly You can overwrite your css but just read this before... https://maxalley.wordpress.com/2015/02/20/bootstrap-style-the-accordion/   and also this https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/bootstrap-3-accordian-onclick-accordion-background-should-be-change/98839/3

Answer (score 0):

I am just updating Shivkumar's answer with the needs and designs with the help of [PaulOB](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/users/PaulOB/activity).. This code works fine with two column support..

the advandtage of the edit is,

1. two column mode
2. clicking the heading backgroud gives toggle effect
3. only one drop down box will be visible at a time

```js
function toggleChevron(e) {
      var theAccordion = $('#accordion');
   $(e.target)
        .prev('.panel-heading')
        .find('i.indicator')
        .toggleClass('glyphicon-minus glyphicon-plus');
        //$('#accordion .panel-heading').css('background-color', 'green');
    theAccordion.find('.panel-heading').removeClass('highlight');
    $(e.target).prev('.panel-heading').addClass('highlight');
}
$('#accordion').on('hidden.bs.collapse', toggleChevron);
$('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', toggleChevron);
$('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('#accordion .in').collapse('hide');
});
```

```css
 .panel-heading .accordion-toggle:after {
 /* symbol for "opening" panels */
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';  /* essential for enabling glyphicon */
 content: "\e113";    /* adjust as needed, taken from bootstrap.css */
 float: right;        /* adjust as needed */
 color: white;         /* adjust as needed */
}
.panel-heading .accordion-toggle.collapsed:after {
 /* symbol for "collapsed" panels */   content: "\e114";    /* adjust as needed, taken from bootstrap.css */
 color: white;
}
.accordion-toggle:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.panel .panel-heading {
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: verdana;
 border-radius:0;
 padding:0;
}
.panel .panel-heading a{
 display:block;
 background: #1FB5AF;
 color: white;
 padding:10px 15px;
 border-radius:3px;
 text-decoration:none;
}
.panel .panel-heading a:hover {
 background: grey;
 color: white;
 text-decoration:none;
}
#accordion .highlight a{
 background:#1FB5AC;/* change colour of selected bar here if needed */
 box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 color:white;
 transition:background 2s ease;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->



<body>
<div class="clearfix panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading highlight">
        <h4 class="panel-title"> <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne"> <i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i> Prof. Ravidra B Bapat, Indian Statistical Institute, Delhi, India </a> </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div style="width: 100%; float: right; text-align: justify "> <img  style=" padding-right: 10px " src="http://sau.int/~ctgtc2016/images/RB_Bapat.jpeg" align="left" > The main areas of research interest of Prof. Bapat are nonnegative matrices,
            matrix inequalities, matrices in graph theory and generalized inverses.
            He has published more than 100 research papers in these areas in reputed
            national and international journals and guided three Ph.D. students. He
            has written books on Linear Algebra, published by Hindustan Book Agency,
            Springer and Cambridge University Press. He wrote a book on Mathematics
            for the general reader, in Marathi, which won the state government award
            for best literature in Science for 2004.
            Prof. Bapat has been on the editorial boards of Linear and Multilinear
            Algebra, Electronic Journal of Linear Algebra, India Journal of Pure and
            Applied Mathematics and Kerala Mathematical Association Bulletin. He
            has been elected Fellow of the Indian Academy of Sciences, Bangalore and
            Indian National Science Academy, Delhi. Prof. Bapat served as President of the Indian Mathematical Society during
            its centennial year 2007-2008. For the past several years he has been
            actively involved with the Mathematics Olympiad Program in India and
            served as the National Coordinator for the Program. Prof. Bapat served as
            Head, ISI Delhi Centre, during 2007-2011. He was awarded the J.C. Bose
            fellowship in 2009. </div>
          <div style="width: 70%; float: left; text-align: justify;"> </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title"> <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo"> <i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Collapsible Group Item #2 </a> </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body"> Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS. </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title"> <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree"> <i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Collapsible Group Item #3 </a> </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body"> Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS. </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading highlight">
        <h4 class="panel-title"> <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne_2"> <i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i> Collapsible Group Item #1 </a> </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne_2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body"> Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS. </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title"> <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo_2"> <i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Collapsible Group Item #2 </a> </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo_2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body"> Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS. </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title"> <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree_2"> <i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Collapsible Group Item #3 </a> </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseThree_2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body"> Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS. </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) --> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed --> 
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript --> 
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">


</script>
</body>
</html>
```